# Select de DB siempre envía el último valor de la lista

Tags: php, html5, ajax, mysqli

Tengo un problema con un formulario en php-ajax y no encuentro una solución.
El formulario carga los datos de un select desde la db, pero al enviar los datos al archivo ajax, siempre y siempre, me envía por POST el último valor del select, independientemente de cual se haya seleccionado.
Cualquier ayuda, sería bien apreciada.

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#formulario").bind("submit",function(){
        // Capturamnos el boton de envío
        var btnEnviar = $("#btnEnviar");
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr("method"),
            url: $(this).attr("action"),
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                /*
                * Esta función se ejecuta durante el envió de la petición al
                * servidor.
                * */
                // btnEnviar.text("Enviando"); Para button 
                btnEnviar.val("Enviando"); // Para input de tipo button
                btnEnviar.attr("disabled","disabled");
            },
            complete:function(data){
                /*
                * Se ejecuta al termino de la petición
                * */
                btnEnviar.val("Enviar formulario");
                btnEnviar.removeAttr("disabled");
            },
            success: function(data){
                /*
                * Se ejecuta cuando termina la petición y esta ha sido
                * correcta
                * */
                $(".respuesta").html(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                /*
                * Se ejecuta si la peticón ha sido erronea
                * */
                alert("Problemas al tratar de enviar el formulario");
            }
        });
        // Nos permite cancelar el envio del formulario
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

```html
<form id="formulario" action="vertr-ajax.php" method="post">
<?php
  $consulta = "SELECT * FROM proveedores";
  $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
?>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Proveedor</th>
            <th scope="col">Usuario</th>
            <th scope="col">Transferir a</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php
          while($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $fila['id'];?></th>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $fila['id'];?>">
        <td><?php echo $fila['nombre'];?></td>
        <input type="hidden" name="proveedor" value="<?php echo $fila['nombre'];?>">
        <td><?php echo $fila['usuario'];?></td>
        <input type="hidden" name="usuarioNuevo" value="<?php echo $fila['usuario'];?>">
        <td>
        <input type="submit" id="btnEnviar" name="btnEnviar" value="Enviar formulario">     </td>
     </tr>
            <?php 
                }
            ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
</form>
<p class="respuesta"></p>
```

y lo que tengo en el vertr-ajax.php es:

```html
$proveedor = $_POST['proveedor'];
$usuarioNuevo = $_POST['usuarioNuevo'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

$consulta = "UPDATE proveedores SET usuario = '123' WHERE nombre = '$proveedor'";
    if ($conexion->query($consulta)==TRUE) {
            $to = "test@test.com";
            $subject = "Hola";
            $message = "Proveedor:".$proveedor.'/<br>';
            $message .= "UsuarioNuevo: ".$usuarioNuevo.'/<br>';
            $message .= "ID: ".$id.'<br>';

            mail($to, $subject, $message);
            $status = 'ok';
        } else {
            $status = 'err';
            
    }

echo $status;
```

Cuando selecciono cualquier valor del select, y hago el envío del formulario, siempre estoy recibiendo el último valor del select.
Dónde está mi error?
**Alguna ayuda por favor?**

Comment: todos tus submit tienen el mismo id. Y, cabe esperar que esté usando el último que tiene asociada la línea del último registro. Debes diferenciarlos asignando ids diferentes (usa el id del registro) como sufijo así: `<input type="submit" id="btnEnviar-<?php echo $fila['id'];?>" name="btnEnviar" value="Enviar formulario">     </td>` liga el observador de evento a click en los elementos tipo submit y desde ellos lanzas el llamado ajax (puedes disparar el form submit si te gusta)

Answer (score 0):

Lo idóneo para no tener esos detalles es tener un `form` por cada conjunto de datos que con su *submit* se enviaran. Es decir:

```
<!-- en la parte de script -->
function mifuncion(id, usrNombre, usrNuevo) {
   $('#id').val(id);
   $('#proveedor').val(usrNombre);
   $('#usuarioNuevo').val(usrNuevo);
   $('#formulario').submit();
}


<!-- En la parte de PHP para mostrar los datos -->
<?php
while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
<form [lo que tienes declarado]>
   <tr>
      [los td junto a los otros tags ]
   </tr>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Desde luego lo anterior te puede marcar ciertas advertencias por la anidación de TAG *"incorrectas"*; fuera de eso para tu caso servirá. Ahora bien, otra opción *(veo usas jQuery)* es crear una función donde pases los valores como parámetros y los pongas en otros TAG (según corresponda) para a ese darle un submit; por ejemplo:

```
<!-- Tu tabla la formas normal; solo omites el inicio y fin del FORM -->
<?php
while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
   <tr>
      [los td junto a los otros tags sin incluir los hidden ]
      <td>
        <input type="submit" id="btnEnviar" name="btnEnviar" value="Enviar formulario"
         onclick='mifuncion(<?php echo $fila['id'].',"'.$fila['nombre'].'","'.$fila['usuario'].'"';?>)'
           />
      </td>
   </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Al final (o en algun lugar de tu HTML) tener:

```
<form [los que tienes declarado] id="formulario"> 
   <!-- Espero no haber omitido alguno -->
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="proveedor" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="usuarioNuevo" value="">
</form>
```